# MySQL Select rectangular region closest to point

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select the region closest to an x/y coordinate from a table of rectangular regions defined by x1/y1, x2/y2 points. The point is outside of any of the rectangular regions.

I have managed to select the regions that are closest in the x axis and the y axis using two separate queries.

The table has columns zoneid(int), mappath(varchar), type(varchar), x1(int), y1(int), x2(int), y2(int)

Nearest region in X-axis

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM mapfiles_zones a
    WHERE a.mappath=? AND a.y1 <= $y AND a.y2 >= $y
    GROUP BY a.zoneid
    ORDER BY abs(a.x1 - $x), abs(a.x2 - $x)
    LIMIT 1
```

Nearest region in Y-axis

```sql
SELECT *
        FROM mapfiles_zones a
        WHERE a.mappath=? AND a.x1 <= $x AND a.x2 >= $x
        GROUP BY a.zoneid
        ORDER BY abs(a.y1 - $y), abs(a.y2 - $y)
        LIMIT 1
```

I am having trouble comparing returned region arrays to determin which is closest in their respective axis.

I cannot use min() on the arrays in PHP because there are other numeric values that end up being analysed. I tried combining the arrays using UNION but get the error

```
number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

How can I get the closest region from these two results in PHP, or better yet, would it be possible to combine these two queries to return the single closest region?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a bit more insight about your table structure?

Comment: @TimOgilvy I added information about the tablestructure

Comment: @Pang sorry, the `AND AND` was from  was from editing out unnecessary statement from the code for this question.

Comment: The bound variables error is probably a separate issue due to your PHP tokens. It's not a mysql UNION error at all, it's a PDO tokenisation issue. Sorry to make you edit again, but you may need to post the PHP too, or in a separate question.

Comment: Consider engineering your SQL separately in mysql workbench or php-myadmin before trying to do it in PHP?

Comment: if you just want shortest value use [least](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function